# Disable Mountain Lion Dictionary Gesture

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, gestures

Ever since Lion I've been using [Better Touch Tool](http://blog.boastr.net/) in order to have the three finger tap gesture trigger a middle click. Now, in Mountain Lion, Apple has changed the in-line dictionary definition gesture from three finger double tap to three finger tap. I am finding that sometimes I get middle click and sometimes I get a dictionary definition. How can I disable Apple's dictionary definition gesture?

Edit: sometimes I am getting both a middle click and a dictionary definition.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-to-disable-three-finger-tap-word-lookup

Comment: Disabling "Look up" feature disables Three-finger-tap gesture in Better Touch Tool - have you found any workaround?

Comment: Yeah, I just kept three finger tap as lookup and made three finger click to be middle click. It takes some getting used to but its bearable.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A similar question was [posted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-to-disable-three-finger-tap-word-lookup) on AskDifferent.

From the [accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57539/479) by [Daniel Lawson](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9388/daniel-lawson):

> In **System Preferences** under *Trackpad* then *Point & Click*,
>   uncheck **Look up**.
>
> [image]